# Observable Network + Network Event + Network Event Listener for Jungrapht

Tags: java, graph-visualization, jung2

I am porting an application from the use of JUNG to using JUNGRAPHT. I'm wondering whether JUNGRAPHT will have ObservableNetwork, NetworkEvent and NetworkEventListener?

JUNGRAPHT is a great opportunity to improve on JUNG so I wouldn't suggest adding an ObservableNetwork class if it weren't part of the direction the project is going. It could instead be part of an Extensions module, or even be left for users of JUNGRAPHT to implement themselves.

It would good to know the direction though. I'm just about to add something of this nature myself.

I need an ObservableNetwork that has getAllVertices and getAllEdges so I might iterate through them, transform them, and re-layout them out in a canvas as per a differing LayoutAlgorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work?

[DefaultListenableGraph](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/graph/DefaultListenableGraph.html)

Comment: That's perfect.